# How do I properly register bootstrap JavaScript into WordPress functions.php?

Tags: functions, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and WordPress and trying to put together a simple page. So, it doesn't surprise me that I'm running into dependency problems adding and registering scripts from both the header and footer.

Is there anything obvious here that I'm missing?

```
<?php 
function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery() { // Register the script like this for a theme: wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

// Register the script like this for a theme:
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery.tweet.js', array( 'jquery' ) );


// Register the script like this for a theme:
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/clock.js', array( 'jquery' ) );


// Register the script like this for a theme:
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/soon.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
//footer scripts

// Register the script like this for a theme:
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/dat.gui.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );


// Register the script like this for a theme:
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/fss.js', array( 'jquery' ) );


// Register the script like this for a theme:
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bgCustom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );


// For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
} add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );

?>
```

Comment: all of your scripts have the same handle name: `custom-script`, each call to `wp_register_script` overwrites the previous one. give them unique handles.

Comment: Please **edit your question** do describe what you *expect* to happen that's not happening, or what's happening *unexpectedly*. Just saying that you're having "dependency problems" doesn't adequately describe the problem to allow us to help answer it.

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned on the [wp_register_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) codex page the handle:

> Should be unique as it is used as a handle for later use with wp_enqueue_script().

You are using the same handle for all your scripts, which won't work.

Besides that, if those scripts are depending on bootstrap, you have to at least register bootstrap before and add it as dependency to the custom scripts registration. Or, enqueue it before enqueuing the custom scripts with [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), which also has an dependencies parameter. Read more about the usage at the linked pages.