# How to add users roles dropdown in registration in wordpress

Tags: plugins, customization

How to add users roles dropdown in  registration in  wordpress

```
 function myplugin_register_form() {

global $wp_roles;

echo '<select name="role">';
foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ): 
echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
 endforeach;
echo '</select>';


}

add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );

add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
    function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'role', trim( $_POST['role'] ) );
        }
    }
```

i used this code in functions.php but not working regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form
2. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user

Instead of **update_user_meta** function in user_register hook use **wp_update_user**

Following is the working example:

```
//1. Add a new form element...
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

    global $wp_roles;

    echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
    foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ) {
       // Exclude default roles such as administrator etc. Add your own
       if ( ! in_array( $value['name'], [ 'Administrator', 'Contributor', ] ) {
          echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
       }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}

//2. Add validation.
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['role'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && trim( $_POST['role'] ) == '' ) {
         $errors->add( 'role_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a role.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {

   $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $_POST['role'] ) );
}
```

Comment: can i know one thing how to add bootstrap styles and scripts in admin plugin page

Comment: Go through this codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Comment: i tried that but not working i am trying to include bootstrap css and javascript fields in my plugin

Comment: This is a different question, ask another question if you not found a solution. Here are the answers hope it'll help you

Don't use bootstrap in admin section, if you still want to use it then use it on specific page like in your plugin.
http://themeshaper.com/2014/08/19/why-bootstrap-is-a-bad-fit-for-wordpress-themes/

follow this also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123405/how-do-i-properly-register-bootstrap-javascript-into-wordpress-functions-php

Comment: Wrote new comment hope this helps http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/195656/29035 @madu

Comment: nice work , its work for me

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php global $wp_roles; ?>

<select name="role">
<?php foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: how to add roles filter to default wordpress registration form?

Comment: go through it. https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

Comment: if add filter filters not working if i select editor its not saving like editor its saving with Default Role ie subscriber in regsitration

Comment: use filter in your themes `functions.php`. if this don't work try to assign higher priority.

Comment: i used filters but its showing dropdown but the user not saving like the role selected

Comment: Where is code for save it? did you follow this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

Comment: yes i do i will paste the code wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26252/discussion-between-madu-and-sohan).

Comment: Please add a **proper** explanation to your code. Code only answers is low quality as I have explaned many times. Such answers deserves a downvote as it is actually useless to future users

Comment: @PieterGoosen code is updated after answer and still waiting for code which is used for save. So what you expect to improve?

Comment: updated code see

Comment: **Explain** how your code works and how it should be used. Simple as that;-)

Comment: originally it was asked, question says itself.i provide a solution for role drop-down. Than i provide solution for update meta. Now i don't understand where the issue? if you please explain it or better post your answer.:-)